# Xubuntu - cannot get DVDs to autoplay

Tags: xubuntu

I have an Xubuntu 17.10 machine and can't get DVDs to autoplay. I gave up on Parole as a player: it won't auto-install the codecs it needs and installing all I thought I needed manually didn't help. So, I installed VLC and it will play DVDs, but I'm trying to get it to autoplay when a DVD is inserted. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most add-ons for Thunar are part of the `xfce4-goodies` group, and if you downloaded it, then consider that all add-ons are already installed.

install

`sudo apt install thunar-volman`

Configuration https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Thunar

2. Settings -> Removable Media -> Multimedia -> Videodisks

`/usr/bin/vlc --fullscreen dvd:///dev/srX`

where `srX` - DVD drive

Comment: The command to run VLC was exactly right and thank you for adding the the full screen argument so I didn't have to look that up.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.